# Save Relation to Newly Created Item with DB generated ID

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot 3 and JPA.
Sample entitles are the following:

```java
public class Node {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "NODE_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer nodeId;

    //...

}
```

```java
public class Edge {

    //...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SRC_NODE_ID", nullable = false)
    private Node sourceNode;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEST_NODE_ID", nullable = false)
    private Node destinationNode;

    //...

}
```

I have a transactional method, that should be able to save a graph with new nodes and edges being added to it, and being saved together.

So there is a JSON object containing nodes[] and edges[], where nodeId would be some temp value (example: temp_node_1023), I want to be able to let the DB assign ID value with ID generation logic, but still edges are referring to nodes by their temp ID.
(multiple UIs and application servers will run concurrently, I cannot let them create IDs)

```java
@Override
@Transactional
public GraphDto saveGraph(int gid, GraphDto graphDto) {
    
    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<>();
    graphDto.getNodes().forEach(nodeDto -> {
        Node Node = new Node();
        // need to know what the ID will be
        //... other fields
        nodes.add(Node);
    });
    nodeRepository.saveAll(nodes);  // <- this will still not save it right?
            
    graphDto.getEdges().forEach(edgeDto -> {
        Edge edge = new Edge();
        edge.setSourceNode(); // need to know how to map temp ID back to DB generated ID
        edge.setDestinationNode(); // need to know how to map temp ID back to DB generated ID
        //... other fields
        edges.add(flowEdge);
    });
    edgeRepository.saveAll(edges);
    
    return getGraph(gid);
}
```

Any good way to achieve this? Thanks!